# How to delay google maps resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API to place multiple places on a map - however it seem that the page loads to quickly, and thereby is not loading all javascript functions and will not place the places on the map.

If i could use the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` function at a certain time after the page has loaded, it should, as far as i know, work as i need.

For example of the problem, please visit http://dev.ateo.dk/sogning/ using incognito. If the map is displaying the places, try again with a new incognito. Most of the time the problem occurs, however sometimes it seem that it is working.

The JS file: http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/default.js and search for "zoom: 14," - this is the function which is supposed to load the map and pinpoint the places

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: wrap it around `setTimeout` method.  Like `setTimeout(function() {google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');}, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function drawMap()
{

   //draw map here
   timer();

} 

var timer=10;

function timers()
{

    timer--;
    if(timer<=0)
    {

        clearTimeout(t);

        drawMarker();

    }

    setTimeout(timers,100);
    //after 1sec the marker will load

}



function drawMarker()
{

     //your code here`

}


<body onload="drawMap()">
```